# Inheritance in web.py?

Tags: python, oop, wsgi, web.py, python-2.5

I am currently developing wep.py application. This is my web application which is binded with web.py and wsgi.

root/main.py

```
import web
import sys
import imp
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#from module import module
from exam import exam
urls = (
    '/exam', 'exam'
)

application = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload = True).wsgifunc()
```

My application has an abstract class called module in module.py in root directory and its purpose is to be inherited by modules.

root/module.py

```
class module:
    def fetchURL(self, url):
        # ...
        return content
```

The lower level module called "exam" would inherits module

root/exam/**init**.py

```
from module import module

class exam(module):
    def getResults(self):
        # error occurs here
        self.fetchURL('math.json')
```

When I call the parent method, web.py raises an exception

> WalkerError: ('unexpected node type', 339)

Environment: Python 2.5

How can I resolve the problem? Thanks

// EDIT 03 July 10:22 GMT+0

The stack trace is as follows

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=1028): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/py/labs_library/index.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 277, in wsgi
     result = self.handle_with_processors()
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 247, in handle_with_processors
     return process(self.processors)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 244, in process
     raise self.internalerror()
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 467, in internalerror
     return debugerror.debugerror()
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\debugerror.py", line 305, in debugerror
     return web._InternalError(djangoerror())
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\debugerror.py", line 290, in djangoerror
     djangoerror_r = Template(djangoerror_t, filename=__file__, filter=websafe)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\template.py", line 845, in __init__
     code = self.compile_template(text, filename)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\web\template.py", line 924, in compile_template
     ast = compiler.parse(code)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 51, in parse
     return Transformer().parsesuite(buf)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 128, in parsesuite
     return self.transform(parser.suite(text))
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 124, in transform
     return self.compile_node(tree)
   File "D:\csvn\Python25\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 167, in compile_node
     raise WalkerError, ('unexpected node type', n)
 WalkerError: ('unexpected node type', 339)
```

If it is possible I would like to turn off the template functionality as I use python only for JSON output for mobile app.

Comment: that error seems to come from [`compiler.transformer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f833e7ec4de1/Lib/compiler/transformer.py#l167). Maybe you have a problem whit your templates? Where exactly is the exception raised, and a more complete stacktrace would be useful.

Comment: @mata It is raised when I call the parent function, which is defined in other python script. I have also posted the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

if you create python module you should add `__init__.py` in top of your hierarchy:

```
dvedit/
  __init__.py
  clipview.py
  filters/
    __init__.py
```

it means that in every directory which will be imported via `from ... import ...` should have `__init__.py` file.

further info available: http://wiki.cython.org/PackageHierarchy

Comment: I have created an `__init__.py` for each packages. The problem is still here.
More info: in `__init__.py`, I imported smtplib `import smtplib` and this also raises "WalkerError: ('unexpected node type', 339)". The stack trace is completely the same as my question

Comment: Could you provide your sys path?

Comment: `['C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\DLLs', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\bin', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'D:\\csvn\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'D:/py/labs_library', 'D:/py/labs_library\\search']`
This is my sys.path. Thank you very much

Comment: Good day. try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/webpy/IPs83UTBUSI

Comment: and Federico Frenguelli answers from: http://groups.google.com/group/webpy/tree/browse_frm/month/2011-07/c6c915a4dd8d13e4?rnum=11&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fwebpy%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fmonth%2F2011-07%3F